# Looking for an alternative way of findFragmentById with binding?

Tags: kotlin, binding, fragment

Is there any way to get a reference to a Fragment without using findFragmentById or findFragmentByTag ??

Answer (score 0):

There is very little information in your question. I assume you use the FragmentManager? There is a getFragments method, you could find your fragment using that. https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#getFragments()

You could also catch the fragment when it attaches, I believe there is an onAttach callback.

If these solutions are not what you are looking for, please provide more information

Comment: As you know, findViewById is deprecated and instead view binding is used, i want to know what  the replacement for  findFragmentById is?

Comment: @bijoop please add any question clarifications to your original question. Comments on answers are used to discuss the particular answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use method **findFragmentById()** from correct library: **androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager**, not from:
**android.app.FragmentManager** - what is deprecated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).